# Load settings from JSON file inside revealing module wih javascript

Tags: javascript, json, revealing-module-pattern

I have several different tools and each tool has many private and public functions. I use one JSON data file to store settings and data needed for the tools.
This because our editors that has no coding knowledge should be able to change the settings and data in the JSON file and adapt all tools to their needs.

All tools are implemented in one module to be able to keep global variables and all tools encapsulated.

I use revealing module for all tools and one more to encapsulate all tools.

```
Example:
var mainModule = (function () {

    var toolOne = (function () {
        function publicFunc () {
            console.log('Some toolOne action.');
        }
        return {
           publicFunc: publicFunc;
        }
    })();

    var toolTwo = (function () {
        function publicFunc () {
            console.log('Some toolTwo action.');
        }
        return {
           publicFunc: publicFunc;
        }
    })();

    return {
        one: toolOne.publicFunc,
        two: toolTwo.publicFunc
    }
})();

mainModule.one();
mainModule.two();
```

Is there any better way to organize all tools?
What is the best way to load JSON file asynchronously and use settings in all modules?

Comment: What are these settings and how are they to applied etc?

Comment: Your code doesn't work. Your inner IIFEs return nothing, so both `moduleOne` and `moduleTwo` are `undefined`. Really, there's no reason to nest the revealing module pattern.

Comment: Use a global promise for the loaded JSON.

Comment: Your code is not JSON so your question doesn't really make sense.  Are you trying to load a file of Javascript code or a file of JSON?  If you're using node.js, you can just let `require()` do all the work for you because it will cache the result.  Each module can just `require()` the module.  The first will load it, the rest will get it from the cache.

Comment: "Really, there's no reason to nest the revealing module pattern" +1

Comment: I changed my question and tried to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Just require the json file at the top of your main module:

```
var settings = require('./path/to/data.json');
```

Comment: Does this loads the file asynchronously?

Comment: no, its sync, but i do wonder what your use-case is that you need this to be async?

Comment: This code should not prevent the page from showing if some problems with loading this file should appear.

Comment: i usually load settings/config files like this at startup, so thats not really an issue